# Set a textfield null if a certain value is in a different textfield

Tags: c#

In C# I want to set a certain textfield to null after I type a value in another textfield. For example, If the Country is not the US, then the state field is null after I click out of the country field.

Comment: can you show us the code that you have written?

Comment: C# doesn't have textfields. Textfields can be in UI frameworks (ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF) or database columns can be referred sometimes as a fields of text. Which textfield do you mean?

Comment: We need to see your code.... At least the portion of the code that is not working.